# How to Turn array of components into one component with nested children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of React context providers, I also have a `children` prop.
I want to recursively iterate through them and append each one to the other's children.

```js
const arr = [A,B,C] // context providers array, dynamic and could change in size

// I need this
return (
 <A>
  <B>
   <C>
    {children}
   </C>
  </B>
 </A>
)
```

My first try was running `reduce` , but i'm getting an `<Unknown />` JSX, when I need a component.

```js
// start with the first component, and begin reducing from the 2nd
    const nestedProviders = arr.slice(1).reduce((accumulator, currentComponent) => {
      return React.cloneElement(accumulator, { children: currentComponent });
    }, arr[0]);
```

Just to clarify, I need a component, not JSX.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just want to say that you can use `arr.reduce((accumulator, currentComponent) => {
    return React.cloneElement(accumulator, { children: currentComponent });
});` because when you don't pass a second arg to reduce the first element will the initial accumulator's value.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it my self, if anyone is interested, I was missing the `({children})` callback.

```js
arr.reduce((GlobalProvider, NewProvider) => ({ children }) => (
      <GlobalProvider>
        <NewProvider>{children}</NewProvider>
      </GlobalProvider>
    ));
);
```

Comment: Nice, you can just use `arr.reduce((GlobalProvider, NewProvider) => ({ children }) => (<GlobalProvider><NewProvider>{children}</NewProvider></GlobalProvider>));`

Comment: How do you pass props tho? Is it possible to use an array like: `const arr = [<A withProp="foo" />, <B />, <C anotherProps="bar" />]` and reduce them as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with reduce:

```
const components = [A, B, C, D];
const MasterComponent = components.reverse().reduce((masterComponent, CurrComponent) =>
   <CurrComponent>
     { masterComponent }
   </CurrComponent>
, null);

return <MasterComponent/>;
```

So we iterate the components in reverse and then build up the nested component from there.

Comment: check my answer, I think youre missing the `children`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version of the `reduce`, where the children are passed as the initial value:

```
const providers = [A, B, C];

function MyCombinedProvider(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    {providers.reduce(
      (accChildren, NextProvider) => (
        <NextProvider>{accChildren}</NextProvider>
      ),
      children
    )}
  );
}
```

> TypeScript might infer the return type as `ReactNode` and give you an error. As a workaround, just wrap the reduce block in a fragment: `return (<>{components.reduce(...)}</>)`.